# Video hosting platform for e-learning system

Tags: web-apps, video

I have a customer that offers free and paid online video classes for their own customers. These videos are curretly stored on the FTP area of their site, the access control is managed entirely by their web application and the videos are displayed on the web pages with a simple javascript player.

Since I'm currently changing some things on this system's platform, I'd like to offer a more robust and secure alternative for this whole video hosting matter, making it easy for them to manage their online classes videos and reducing the complexity and storage cost for the web application.

That said, I'm looking for a **Video Hosting platform** with the following requirements:

- Ability to manage either public and private videos
- Embeddable on websites
- Fully localized in Portuguese-Brazil
- Fair prices
- Trial or limited free functionality, so my customer can validate the solution and I can test the integration with the web application

Not mandatory, but extra points to take into account:

- Friendly API for deeper integration with the website
- Nice statistics reports, so they can track their visualization and geographic numbers

Comment: Have you tried Vimeo?

Comment: I've considered looking into it, but at first I wanted to see some options.

Comment: Please do not create tags that could apply to every question (like “software”) or tags that are too vague to be meaningful (like “platform”). Tags indicate what a question is about. See [What are tags, and how should I use them?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) for more information.

Comment: @Gilles Okay I agree, but didn't you narrowed too much now? Just "web-apps" and "video" won't describe the subject here. Why "platform" cannot be there?